# What reputation is needed to flag as spam?

Tags: discussion

We seem to be getting a rush of spam this morning. I see the spams quickly earn lots of downvotes but remain present. Since only 6 spam flags are required to delete the post I'm a bit surprised they manage to attract e.g. 10 downvotes without a corresponding number of spam flags. Maybe we should consider lowering the reputation necessary to flag posts as spam.

Does downvoting a spam post actually achieve anything?

Answer (score 8):

Everyone who can downvote (125 rep) [certainly can flag posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts) (15 rep).

Spam flags are accompanied by a free automatic downvote (which is different from the downvote one can choose to apply).  Closing works similarly, certain close reasons (off topic and NARQ if memory serves me right) carry an automatic -1

Questions with a certain negative score (or 3 spam flags) disappear from the main page. That's all that is really important -- an invisible spam post is harmless and can be deleted at leisure. Note that as a 10k user you can still find unhandled spam posts (and other flags) [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged).